# how i can put from string directly?

Tags: java, android

how i can put from string directly, is say:

My String

```
String Title = "THIS IS TITLE";
```

put in

```
parameters.put("title", title.getText().toString());
```

I could do it with getText?

Below my complete code

```
public class sendNotification {
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String URLNot = "";
    String title = "PRUEBA";

    private void sendComienzo (){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLNot, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

                parameters.put("title", title.getText().toString());

                return parameters;

            }

        };
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }
}
```

Comment: `title.getText()` doesn't even compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title is a string, not a EditText.. you cannot use `getText` on it

hence,

```
parameters.put("title", title);
```

is enough... getText normally you used to get string from `EditText` but it returns `Editable` hence convert it `toString()` for manipulation to whatever string can use.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the `put(key, value)` method should be the value that you want to assign to the object mapped by `key`.

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V))

```
parameters.put("title", title);
```

Should work fine.